# Pyramid Creation in Spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I have a requirement to create a pyramid in Spotfire. I have searched a lot and didn't get anything concrete as to how this can be achieved. I have created a simple pyramid in excel. Is it possible for me to achieve this in Spotfire.
[image]

Could i get a path on this.

Comment: what version? 7.6 has waterfall charts... that is *close* to what you want it seems

Comment: We have 7.8 version and do you have any inputs as to how i can implement that in waterfall charts.

Comment: This can be done by generating html in python to replace the html of a text area.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample code that i can use to try out the feature.

Comment: Sorry i can't. We're on 7.5 currently and i'm not sure it will actually be possible, but that is where i'd start is all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to create the pyramid in Spotfire on the dataset. The way to achieve this is by creating a stacked chart on two columns. Then we can make the color of the column which we have just used to stack up the dataset as white, so that this gets hidden on the visualization. Once this is done, we have to play around the expression of the this column based on the dataset to make the stack charts look like pyramid. 
For example, i had to plot the pyramid of students according to subjects in the college. So i used the below expression to give me the desired results:

UniqueCount([student_id]) as [id], (Max(UniqueCount([student_id])) - UniqueCount([student_id])) / 2 as [dummy]

In the above expression dummy column is the column which i have made white, so that i get the desired pyramid.

Screenshot below of the pyramid i was able to create:
[image]

Once i was able to get the pyramid, i unchecked the legends and x-axis to not show the expressions.

I am not sure, if any other way exits to get the desired result, but the above way helped me achieve the desired result.